# Setting up FTP server to be used with Wi-Fi Hotspot

Tags: windows, ftp, wifi

I am looking for a software that can set up a FTP or a similar sharing protocol that can help me access my physical storage inside my home PC using a Wi-Fi hotspot, and preferably be iPhone compatible (in case of using FTP I know that it will be compatible). I've tried using WinSCP but none of the options there make any sense. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a really simple manner:

1. Install python from [here](https://www.python.org/).
2. Open a command prompt and change directory to the top directory of what you wish to serve.
3. Install the [twisted framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) with `pip install twisted`
4. Start and ftp server with `twistd -n ftp`

You have your FTP server up an running.

If you would like to have this running all of the time, rather than on demand, consider [running as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666373/start-python-py-as-a-service-in-windows).

Then start finding out all of the other marvellous things that you can do with your new toys, (python & twisted).